# Unable to access static Class variable in different directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, class, static

I have problem when I try to read value in some variables in Class.
my file structure:

```
PROJECT/
|_ MODULE1/
|_ |_ server1.py
|_ |_ config/
|_ |_ |_ bridge.py
|_ MODULE2/
|_ |_ server2.py
|_ |_ v_config/
|_ |_ |_ v_bridge.py
|_ TESTS/
|_ |_ test_configuration.py
|_ |_ test_data.py
```

And now, in test_configuration.py first I start both servers in threads and do some other configurations. Code looks like that:

```
from MODULE1.server1 import Server1
from MODULE2.server2 import Server2
from MODULE1.config.bridge import ImportantBridge
class TestConfigureServer(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        if server1.is_alive is False:
            init_server1 = Server1()
            thread = threading.Thread(target=init_server1.start, args=(), daemon=True)
            thread.start()
        if server2.is_alive is False:
            init_server2 = Server2()
            thread = threading.Thread(target=init_server2.start, args=(), daemon=True)
            thread.start()

    def check_status(self):
        print(ImportBridge.some_variable)  <--- this print output is False
        if ImportBridge.some_variable:
             print("its work")
        return ImportBridge.some_variable
```

Then in test_data.py I make some asserts and one ot these run method in test_configuration.py
Code looks similar to that:

```
from TESTS.test_configuration import TestConfigureServer
from MODULE1.config.bridge import ImportantBridge
class TestData(TestConfigureServer):
[...]
    def do_something():
    [...]
    if self.check_status():
         assert ImportantBridge.some_variable = True
```

So problem is somewhere in tests or in Bridge because when server is run I have 100% sure that the some_variable has change to True

Here is Bridge code looks like:

```
ImportantBridge:
    some_variable = False
```

and server change it correctly (when I put print somewhere in Server1.py or other module files it's print True) Also when I make request to this server to return this some_variable also it's returns True value.
I try to init this ImportantBridge
also I writhe method in this class to return this some_variable but in every cases in tests it is "default" value False when in server1.py or other .py files in MODULE1 (yes I don't put here every file because it's almost 40 files) the value is True - what is correct becuase, like I said it's change before do_something() in TestData was executed.

What I do wrong? Someone please can explain me this?

Comment: It is possible that your threads simply havent had time to start yet. You might consider just adding some artificial delay to give the servers time to set `some_variable = True`

Comment: @Gaberocksall I have time.sleep(1) after thread.start() and also I have logs where I see when thread with server start. After this the rest of code was executed. Also some_variable is changing in server so server must be alive and proper set to change this.